# Integral $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{e^{-x}} \cos3xdx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{e^{-x}} \cos3xdx$$
using the intergral by parts formula
$$\int{f(x).g(x)'}\mathrm{d}x = (f(x).g(x)) - \int{f'(x)g(x)dx}$$
so it should be
$${{{e^{-x}}.\frac{1}{3}\cos(3x)}} - \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{-e^{-x}\frac{1}{3}\cos(3x)dx}$$
but the correct next step should be
$${{{-e^{-x}}.\cos(3x)}} - \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{-e^{-x}(-3\sin(3x))dx}$$

which should be the correct step?

Comment: If you choose $g'(x)=\cos 3x$, then $g(x)=\int \cos 3x \, dx=\frac{1}{3}\sin 3x$. If you choose $f(x)=\cos 3x$, then you would have $f'(x)=-3\sin 3x$.

Comment: It is not clear which is f and which is g.  In any case, $\frac{cos(3x)}{3}$ is wrong.

Comment: Check your third step.  The final result is $$\frac{1}{10} \left(1-3 e^{-\pi /2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this question. (i) First you can write $e^{-x}$ as $(-e^{-x})'$ and then apply the integration by parts forrmula, which gives other terms and, up to numerical factors, the integral of $e^{-x}\sin(3x).$ Then once more
write $e^{-x}$ as $(-e^{-x})'$ and  apply the integration by parts formula again, which gives you back other terms and the desired integral with a number in front of it, so you can solve for the desired integral. (ii) First you can write $\cos(3x)$ as $(\frac{1}{3}\sin(3x))'$ and then apply the integration by parts formula, which gives other terms and, up to numerical factors, the integral of $e^{-x}\sin(3x).$ Then write $\sin(3x)$ as $(-\frac{1}{3}\cos(3x))'$ and apply the integration by parts formula again which gives you back other terms and the desired integral with a number in front of it, so you can solve for the desired integral.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos(3x)=Re(e^{3ix})$$

let us compute

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{x(-1+3i)}dx=$$

$$\Bigl[\frac{1}{-1+3i}e^{(-1+3i)x}\Bigr]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-x}\cos {3x}dx = \text{int. by parts} =\left(-e^{-x}\cos{3x}\right)_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-3\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-x}\sin {3x}dx\\
= 1-3\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-x}\sin {3x}dx\\
= \text{int. by parts} = 1-3\left( \left( -e^{-x}\sin{3x} \right)_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} + 3\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-x}\cos {3x}dx \right) \\
=1-3\left(e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}} + 3\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-x}\cos {3x}dx \right) \\
= 1 - 3e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}-9I\\$

Now we have:
$$10I= 1 - 3e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}} \iff I = \frac{1 - 3e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}}{10}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

By parts, twice,

$$\int e^{-x}f(x)\,dx=-e^{-x}f(x)+\int e^{-x}f'(x)\,dx=-e^{-x}f(x)-e^{-x}f'(x)+\int e^{-x}f''(x)\,dx$$

so that

$$\int e^{-x}(f(x)-f''(x))\,dx=-e^{-x}(f(x)+f'(x)).$$